# Как создать AlertDialog со списком и картинками у каждого пункта списка?

Tags: android, xamarin

Нашел код под Android studio, а как правильно переписать его под Visual studio Xamarin Android не могу разобраться. Пробовал переписать вот этот код: http://dev.androidteam.ru/snippets/dialog/items-with-images-in-dialog
Уже целый день пытаюсь разобраться как такое реализовать, но никак не выходит. Под Xamarin похоже мало что есть на русском языке. AlertDialog со списком создать просто, а вот как добавить картинки в список? Надеюсь объясните как такое реализовать - очень хочется разобраться. Заранее спасибо.

[image: Список элементов с картинками]

Comment: В каждом списке используется адаптер. Каждый адаптер использует разметку для пункта списка. Вам надо использовать свой адаптер + свою разметку в методе `getView` адаптера. В нём же и отображать картинку в её контенере

Comment: Можно ли пример такого списка в Xamarin? Я пробовал разобраться с созданием адаптера, но у меня ничего не вышло.

Comment: Я в Xamarin не умею. Только ява, только хардкор)

Answer (score 1):

Работа с AlertDialog в Xamarin Android реализована также как и нативно +/- нюансы. 
Ниже один из вариантов как сделать. Код не тестировался!. Пардон за оформление

1. Идем в NuGet и качаем Square.Picasso.
2. Сразу обновляем Square.OkHttp. Чтобы с последними версиями Xamarin не было проблем.
3. Далее, Content View (custom_dialog_with_img.xml).

   `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#ffffff">`

   ```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/my_items"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:fillViewport="true"
           android:scrollbars="vertical" />
   ```

   `</RelativeLayout>`
4. Далее, Item View (item_with_img.xml).

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="2">

     <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/img_block"
       android:layout_width="30dp"
       android:layout_height="35dp"
       android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
       android:layout_weight="0.02"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
         android:id="@+id/img"
         android:layout_width="20dp"
         android:layout_height="20dp"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

     </RelativeLayout>

     <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
         android:id="@+id/name"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
         android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
         android:layout_weight="1.98"
         android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   5. Создаем Адаптер

   `public class CustomAdapterForDialogWithList : BaseAdapter<Model>
               {
                   private readonly Context _context;
                   private readonly IList<Model> _items;
                   private readonly int _layoutId;`

   ```
               public CustomAdapterForDialogWithList(Context context, IList<Model> items, int layoutId)
               {
                   _context = context;
                   _items = items;
                   _layoutId = layoutId;
               }

               /// <summary>
               /// Получить ид из списка
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="position"></param>
               /// <returns></returns>
               public override long GetItemId(int position)
               {
                   return _items[position].Id;
               }

               /// <summary>
               /// 
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="position"></param>
               /// <param name="convertView"></param>
               /// <param name="parent"></param>
               /// <returns></returns>
               public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
               {
                   ViewHolder holder;

                   if (convertView == null)
                   {
                       var inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                       convertView = inflater.Inflate(_layoutId, null, true);
                       holder = new ViewHolder
                       {
                           TitleView = (AppCompatTextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Layout.name),
                           ImageView = (AppCompatImageView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Layout.img)
                       };
                       convertView.SetTag(_layoutId, holder);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.GetTag(_layoutId);
                       holder.TitleView.Text = _items[position].Title;
                       Picasso.With(_context).Load(_items[position].Url).Placeholder(Resource.Drawable.error).Error(Resource.Drawable.error).Into(holder.ImageView);
                   }

                   return convertView;
               }

               /// <summary>
               // /// Количество элементов в списке
               /// </summary>
               public override int Count => _items?.Count ?? 0;

               /// <summary>
               /// Получить элемент из списка зная его индекс
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="position"></param>
               /// <returns></returns>
               public override Model this[int position] => _items[position];
           }

           public class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
           {
               /// <summary>
               /// Текстовое поле
               /// </summary>
               public AppCompatTextView TitleView { get; set; }

               /// <summary>
               /// Изображение
               /// </summary>
               public AppCompatImageView ImageView { get; set; }
           }
         }
   ```

   `public class Model
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Url { get; set; }
   }`
5. И последнее

   ```
   var dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
   var inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
   var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.custom_dialog_list_mobile, null);

   var recycleView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.my_items);
   recycleView.HasFixedSize = true;

   var adapter = new CustomAdapterForDialogWithNumberList(_context, new Model() {...}, Resource.Layout.custom_dialog_with_img);
   recycleView.SetAdapter(adapter);
   dialog.SetView(view);
   dialog.Show();
   ```

PS. BaseAdapter переделать на RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Я уже нашел подобный код только для ListView. Не пойму только зачем использовать Square.Picasso - это наверно какой-то дополнительный компонент. Под себя буду переписывать данный пример.

Comment: ListView считается устаревшим компонентом. Square.Picasso  сторонний компонент для загрузки картинок. Более удобный чем. То что доступно из коробки.

Comment: Я не нашел кода где используется Square.Picasso в этом коде, поэтому его не использовал. Адаптер надо создавать RecyclerView.Adapter, но он имеет совсем иной код для работы адаптера. Очень помог демонстрационный код тут: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/

Comment: Вызов диалога несколько отличается у меня, т.к. требуется создавать                                                                             mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                recycleView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);             Вот мой полностью рабочий пример такого alertDialog: https://yadi.sk/d/8KPhXd1k3L6ShU - может кому пригодится ещё или будут замечания по коду.